# How to use private submit to hide from feed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, feed, railscasts, public-activity

In the valuations form there is a submit button and a `<%= f.submit :private %>` button. If private submit is clicked the submitted info will be hidden to other user's who view the profile.

How can we also use `<%= f.submit :private %>` to hide submitted info from showing on the feed?

**activities/index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Feed</h1>
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
<% if current_user == @user %>
    <%= render_activity activity %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render_activity activity %> #We'd need to make .public_valuations work with this without getting an undefined method error.
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**activities_controller.rb**

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(owner_id: current_user.following_ids, owner_type: "User")
  end
end
```

For brevity I'll only include `_create` (there is also `update` and `destroy`). Every time a user submits a valuation it pops up on the feed, how can we make only [`public_valuations`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323201/how-to-use-private-submit-to-hide-from-profile) show?

**public_activity/valuation/_create.html.erb**

```
<% if activity.trackable %>
  <%= link_to activity.trackable.name, activity.trackable %></b>
<% else %>
  which has since been removed 
<% end %>
```

**valuation.rb**

```
class Valuation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_taggable
  validates :name, presence: true
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked owner: ->(controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user }

    def public?
      private == true ? false : true
    end

  scope :randomize, -> do
      order('RANDOM()').
      take(1)
    end
end
```

**users_controller**

```
 def show
   if
     @valuations = @user.valuations
   else
     @valuations = @user.public_valuations
   end
 end
```

**user.rb**

```
#gets public valutations or nil, if there's no public valutation
def public_valuations
  valuations.find(&:public?)
end
```

I gained almost all of my activities code form this railscasts episode: http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity.

This is how we made the private submit work for the profile:
[How to use private submit to hide from profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323201/how-to-use-private-submit-to-hide-from-profile)

Thank you so much for your time!

### UPDATE

Since we couldn't resolve the issue via the public_activity gem I created the public activity from scratch and am attempting to resolve this issue here: 
[How to make private activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786536/how-to-make-private-activities?noredirect=1#comment47703235_29786536)

Comment: I think there's better way to make something private:
For ex. - add new boolean field :private. On your form add checkbox for this boolean. And than, in view, do a check
````<% if activity.private %>

do something..
<% else %>
do something else...
<% end %>````

Comment: @Avdept thanks for the suggestion! I have `t.boolean :private default false` in my schema for valuations. This is represented in the valuations _form. In the view do `if else` sounds good. Should I do it in `activities/index.html.erb` or maybe it's better in the controller? Is there any more code or info I can give you to make your comment into an answer?

Comment: your if - else clause you have to put into view, in the moment you're rendering your entity. If i understood correctly - you dont want to show something if this 'something' has flagged as private. Am i right?

Comment: Thanks @Avdept for helping to move the ball. I updated the question. How can we make .public_valuations work with `<%= render_activity activity %>`? I'm guessing we'd have to do something with the controller now.

Comment: are you going to render something for those that are private?

Comment: I'm only going to render `public_valuations` @Avdept. I don't want the private stuff to show to other users. There are other attributes such as `public_habits`, `public_goals` but for this question I figured we'd keep it simple and focus on just making `public_valuations` work and hiding regular/private valuations.

Comment: There are few ways of how you can do this.
First is - add named scope into your model like

`scope :public, -> { where(private: false) } `
and than use this method on your collection, and it will look like

`@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.public.order("created_at desc").where(owner_id: current_user.following_ids, owner_type: "User")`

Comment: Where am I adding `:public` @Avdept I don't see it in your code snippet? And I already have `def public? private == true ? false : true end` in valuation.rb. Am I suppose to take that out to avoid the error I'm getting: `You tried to define a scope named "public" on the model "Valuation", but Active Record already defined a class method with the same name.`

Comment: @Avdept I got that code from his answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323201/how-to-use-private-submit-to-hide-from-profile so I think I need that snippet for the purposes of that question unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: You dont need public methods. Since you have private - public is opposite of private

Comment: @Avdept I added public to: `@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.public.order` and in the valuations model I tried `def public? private == true ? false : true end` but that gave me: `NoMethodError in ActivitiesController#index private method 'public' called for...` I tried `def public? !private end` but that gave me: `SyntaxError in ActivitiesController#index /models/valuation.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected '!', expecting ';' or '\n' def public? !private end ^ /models/valuation.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input`

Comment: And like I said @Avdept I tried `scope :public, -> { where(private: false) }` but that gave me: `You tried to define a scope named "public" on the model "Valuation", but Active Record already defined a class method with the same name.` Thanks for helping me this far! Do you mind providing an answer so I can award you the bounty?

Comment: Try to use different scope name, like :public_records, or something similar

Comment: I updated the question and offered an answer based upon your suggestions. Hopefully this will provide clarity for what I'm doing wrong @Avdept. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

### FAILED ATTEMPT

at Avdept's suggestions:

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.not_private.order("created_at desc").where(owner_id: current_user.following_ids, owner_type: "User")
    end
end
```

In **valuations.rb**

```
def public? !private end => def public?; !private; end;
scope :not_private, -> { where(private: false) }
```

This gives:

```
SyntaxError in ActivitiesController#index (for line: def public? !private end => def public?; !private; end;)
/Users/galli01anthony/Desktop/Pecoce/app/models/valuation.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected '!', expecting ';' or '\n' def public? !private end => def public?; !private; end; ^ /Users/galli01anthony/Desktop/Pecoce/app/models/valuation.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting end-of-input def public? !private end => def public?; !private; end; ^
```

Comment: `def public? !private end => def public?; !private; end;` Change this way.
For scope - change name from :public to something like :not_private, since public is keyword. ALso scope should be inside model, not controller